# Compare two values from two database table

Tags: mysql

I have many database tables where I have data from the registered user. When the user has been deleted, data from that specific user is only deleted from one database table (`table 1` for example).

So, I need to compare `current_user_id` from all other related tables with `user_id` from `table 1` and if that value doesn't exist in `table 1` all other values in those tables with that specific id need to be deleted.

For example, if I have these two database tables:

```
table 1
id | user_id|
------------
1  | 14     |
2  | 15     | 
3  | 16     |
4  | 17     |
```

```
table 2
id  | current_user_id |
----------------------
21  | 14             |
22  | 15             | 
23  | 16             |
24  | 17             |
25  | 18             |
```

`user_id` and `current_user_id` are the same value from two different tables.

I need to loop through the `user_id`, compare with `current_user_id` and to delete every `current_user_id` if the `user_id` missing that value.  (already deleted)

For example:
If I have `current_user_id=14` and I don't have `user_id=14` then I need `current_user_id=14` to be deleted.

Comment: You do have `user_id=14`. You don't have `user_id=18`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize a sub-query:

```
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE current_user_id NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM table1
);
```

`NOT IN` specifies that it should delete any records whose value is not found in the selected result set of the sub-query.

Answer (score 2):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
delete t2 from table2 t2
where not exists (
  select 1 from table1 t1
  where t1.user_id = t2.current_user_id
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/emYCCjitCohtT3KWUmhVp9/1).
Or with a `LEFT JOIN` of `table2` to `table1` which will delete the unmatched rows:

```
delete t2 
from table2 t2 left join table1 t1
on t1.user_id = t2.current_user_id
where t1.user_id is null;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/emYCCjitCohtT3KWUmhVp9/3).